# How to substitute an end of line character from Salesforce Text Area field

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi, jscript

I am using a text area field in Salesforce as a RecipientNote for a Docusign envelope created using a custom button in Salesforce.
The syntax below handles any commas or special characters, but I'm unable to find the correct syntax to preserve any linebreaks in the Program_Exception_Notes__c field.

```
;RecipientNote~{!JSENCODE(URLENCODE(SUBSTITUTE(Sales_Program_Info__c.Program_Exception_Notes__c,",","_COMMA_")))}
```

I have tried the following but none worked. Any ideas?

```
'{!SUBSTITUTE(JSENCODE(URLENCODE(SUBSTITUTE(Sales_Program_Info__c.Program_Exception_Notes__c,",","_COMMA_"))),"%0D%0A","\\n")}'
'{!JSENCODE(URLENCODE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Sales_Program_Info__c.Program_Exception_Notes__c,"\r\n","\\n"),",","_COMMA_")))}'
```

Comment: Hi Bob, if you are populating a custom Recipient Note each time, any reason why you choose to do it from a custom Salesforce field instead of the Recipient information within the DocuSign visualforce page?

Comment: The person who populates the note is not the same person that generates and sends the envelope. Additionally, the note is generated using a custom button to populate the recipients and notes, etc.

Comment: Sorry, the above should say "the **envelope** is generated..."

Answer (score 1):

I would process your text in a couple of steps in jscript.

1. first break the text into an array of string lines
2. escape characters you are looking to correct
3. then reassemble using the "\n" when you put it back together into a var
4. Then after all that, URL and JS encode that string variable.